# Can you have multiple @SpringBootTest classes each with their own inner @TestConfiguration defining the same bean without conflicts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-test

To illustrate the issue I have two separate @SpringBootTest classes each of which have an inner @TestConfiguration static class both of which create the same bean.

When I run TestB I see that the "stringBeans" bean from TestA is being created and used and vice versa. Why is this? I want to be able to create different tests that define the same bean but with that bean configured differently. How can I achieve this?

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
public class TestA {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public String stringBeans() {
            System.out.println("Creating string bean from Test A");
            return "Test A";
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("Running Test A");
    }
}
```

When running the above test I see the following output:

Creating string bean from Test B

Running Test A

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
public class TestB {

    @Autowired
    String stringBeans;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public String stringBeans() {
            System.out.println("Creating string bean from Test B");
            return "Test B";
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println("Running Test B");
        assertThat(stringBeans).isEqualTo("Test B");
    }
}
```

When running the above test the assert fails and I see the following output:

Creating string bean from Test A

Running Test B

I have tried creating separate classes annotated with @TestConfiguration and using @Import to pull them into each respective test but that does not resolve this issue consistently.

Comment: Please include the packages for your test classes.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Spring Boot 2.4.0. Can you add your Spring Boot version and also all your imports for both tests?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @rieckpil . Turned out I had an additional component scan configured in my application.yml in my test/resources folder (see answer below). By the way your Test Spring applications using AWS with Testcontainers and LocalStack blog post is fantastic! Saved me a huge amount of time. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Great that you could figure out the issue on your own +1

Answer (score 0):

I was testing a [Spring Cloud Function](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function) and it turned out I had a component scan defined in the application.yml in the test/resources folder that was causing both inner @TestConfiguration classes to be evaluated. So you need to be super careful with your test setup otherwise weird behaviour that can be difficult to trace can happen.

In this example I had my classes all defined under com.example.demo and an application.yml as follows

```
spring: 
     cloud:
       function:
         scan:
           packages: com.example.demo
```

The tests run as expected after removing this unnecessary scan.